# When applying softmax over multiple dimensions of a tensor, does the order in which those dimensions are matter?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

Lets say i have a tensor of order 256, dimensions indexed from 0 to 255.

Lets say i am writing a function implementing the softmax operation because i am a newbie and i want to understand the fundamental principles of machine learning.

Lets say the softmax is to be applied to dimensions 2 51 and 139.

Will the final result stay the same, regardless of whether i do softmax(2,51,139) or softmax(51,2,139) or softmax(139,51,2)?

Disregard the obvious problem of floating point operations not being really commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Softmax is applied along a single dimension, not along many dimensions.

For instance, in the [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html) you can see that softmax receives param dim to specify the dimension over which it is:

> Parameters
>
> **dim** (int) – A dimension along which Softmax will be computed (so every slice along dim will sum to 1).

If you are referring to applying softmax sequentially over different dimensions, then the answer is that the order certainly matters. In the final result, only the dimension to which the softmax was applied last would be normalized.